# How to detect scroll completed or end after scrolling in CarouselView in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a `CarouselView` and I want to have some animation after Items are scrolled manually (by swiping left or right on CarouselView). I want to know when the scroll animation is complete or ended. Is there any way, I did not find anything related to this in the Official Docs.

**Here is my code**

```xml
<CarouselView x:Name="carouselView" Scrolled="CarouselViewScrolled" Loop="False" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" >
    <CarouselView.ItemsSource>
        <x:Array Type="{x:Type ContentView}">
            <ContentView>
                <!--Defining View 1-->
            </ContentView>
            <ContentView>
                <!--Defining View 2-->
            </ContentView>
            <ContentView>
                <!--Defining View 3-->
            </ContentView>
    </CarouselView.ItemsSource>
</CarouselView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, use `CurrentItemChanged` instead of `Scrolled` property of `CarouselView`.

**Change your XAML as**

```xml
<CarouselView x:Name="carouselView" CurrentItemChanged="CarouselViewItemChanged">
...
```

If you want to get current Item after Swiping to a new Item use `carouselView.Position`.

**In your C# Code behind**

```cs
void CarouselViewItemChanged(object sender, CurrentItemChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Position: " + carouselView.Position);
}
```

[Refer this for Official Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/carouselview/interaction)